# Synchronize subset of photos or music to phone

Tags: sync, gui

I am looking for a tool or process to synchronize a subset of music or photo folders on Win10 to phone or Raspberry (for MPD).

- select subset of music directory tree
- copy

later:

- select other music, deselect some folders
- copy newly selected to phone, remove deselected

I could

```
dir /d /as > files.txt
```

edit it and feed it to robocopy or rsync, but there should be nicer ways ..

Answer (score 0):

Found that the [ranger](https://ranger.github.io/)  file manager supports persistent tags. Files with tags can be listed and fed into a rsync script.

```
$ ranger --list-tagged-files='*'
/d/gitprojects/ranger/ranger.py
/d/gitprojects/ranger/README.md
```